# Triangle of forces

Tags: mathematical-physics

Forces equal to $5P$, $12P$ and $13P$ acting on a particle are in equilibrium ;find ,by geometric construction and by calculation ,the angles between their directions?

I have an problem that, With three forces how can I use Lami's rule?

Comment: For what it's worth, $5^2 + {12}^2 = {13}^2$.

Comment: of course but what about angles of these lines of forces..?

Comment: @Jose is clearly hinting that the angle between the $5P$ force and the $12P$ force is $\pi/2$...

Comment: Hold on.  @himu, by Lami's rule, do you mean this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lami%27s_theorem)?

Comment: yeah! sure but same question can one ask that if the forces are changed by  $7P$ ,$5P$ and $8P$.

Comment: If so, by reconstructing the force diagram as in the linked Wikipedia article in my previous comment, clearly the angle between the $5P$ force and the $12P$ force is $\pi/2$, as @jameselmore has so kindly pointed out.

Comment: Sure, in general you just need to use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: that's actually a picky problem ,because how one solve with only forces with no idea of any ,even one of the angles between the two other forces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more systematic approach.  Suppose the $3$ forces acting on the particle are $\vec F_1$, $\vec F_2$, and $\vec F_3$.  Then, we are given that the sum $\vec F$ is zero:

$$\vec F=\vec F_1+\vec F_2+\vec F_3=0$$

and are given the magnitudes of each of the forces.  We are asked for the angles between the pairs.  We need, therefore, three independent equations.

To do this, we form the inner product of $\vec F$ with each of the three forces.  Proceeding we obtain,

$$F_1^2+F_1F_2\cos \phi_{12}+F_1F_3\cos \phi_{13} =0 \tag 1$$

$$F_1F_2\cos \phi_{12}+F_2^2+F_2F_3\cos \phi_{23} =0 \tag 2$$

$$F_1F_3\cos \phi_{13}+F_2F_3\cos \phi_{23}+F_3^2 =0 \tag 3$$

Equations $(1)-(3)$ constitute a linear system of $3$ equations in the $3$ unknow cosines.  The solution to the system is given by

$$\begin{align}
\cos \phi_{12}&=\frac{F_3^2-(F_1^2+F_2^2)}{2F_1F_2} \tag 4\\\\
\cos \phi_{13}&=\frac{F_2^2-(F_1^2+F_3^2)}{2F_1F_3} \tag 5\\\\
\cos \phi_{23}&=\frac{F_1^2-(F_2^2+F_3^2)}{2F_2F_3} \tag 6\\\\
\end{align}$$

For the specific problem herein, we are given that $F_1=5$, $F_2=12$, and $F_3=13$.  Using these values in $(4)-(6)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\cos \phi_{12}&=0 \\\\
\cos \phi_{13}&=-\frac{5}{13} \\\\
\cos \phi_{23}&= -\frac{12}{13}\\\\
\end{align}$$

and therefore the angles between the force vectors are

$$\begin{align}
\phi_{12}&=\frac{\pi}{2} \\\\
\phi_{13}&=\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{5}{13}\right) \\\\
\phi_{23}&= \pi-\arccos\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

let $\vec x\parallel\vec F_1, \vec x \perp \vec y$

$\vec x:$

$\angle \vec F_2=\alpha$, $\angle \vec F_3=\beta$

$\vec y:$

$\angle \vec F_2=\frac {\pi}{2} - \alpha$, $\angle \vec F_3=\frac {\pi}{2} - \beta$

$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   F_1 + F_2 \cdot \cos \alpha + F_3 \cdot \cos \beta = 0
\\
0 + F_2 \cdot \sin \alpha + F_3 \cdot \sin \beta = 0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$

$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases} 
   F_1 + F_2 \cdot \cos \alpha + F_3 \cdot \cos \beta = 0
\\
12 \cdot \sin \alpha = -13 \cdot  \sin \beta
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$

$\sin \alpha = - \frac {13}{12} \cdot \sin \beta$

$\cos^2 \alpha = 1 - \frac {169}{144} \cdot \sin^2 \beta=\frac {169}{144} \cdot \cos^2 \beta - \frac {25}{144}$

$ 5 + 12 \cdot \cos \alpha + 13 \cdot \cos \beta = 0$

$ 12 \cdot \cos \alpha =- 13 \cdot \cos \beta - 5$

$ 144 \cdot \cos^2 \alpha =(13 \cdot \cos \beta + 5)^2$

$169 \cdot \cos^2 \beta - 25 = 169 \cdot \cos^2 \beta + 130 \cdot \cos \beta + 25$

$130 \cdot \cos \beta = -50$

$\cos \beta = \frac {5}{13}, \beta < \pi$

$ \beta = 1.176$

$ \sin \alpha = -1$

$\alpha = \frac {3 \cdot \pi}{2}$

Answer:

$\angle \vec F_1 \vec F_2 = \frac {3 \cdot \pi}{2}, \angle \vec F_1 \vec F_3 = 1.176$

## EDIT: Stupid mistake